# In a function prototype it shows an error

Tags: java, arrays, string, function

it shows cannot find symbol- class string
I am writing a program for a report card. This function is to accept names. Pls help

```
public static string accept_name() {
    String STR[]=new String[40];
    System.out.println("Enter 40 students names");
    for(int a=0;a<=39;a++) {
        STR[a]=br.readLine();
    }
    return (STR);
}
```

Comment: Java ain't C. It's String not string. Java doesn't have functions. Java doesn't have prototypes.

Comment: Thank you! Now it shows in compatible types for    STR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `String` not `string`.

Java types are case sensitive.

Also, you declare return type is `String`, but you actually returns `STR` which is of type `String[]` (array of `String`s).

You need to change the return type to `String[]`, or decide which `String` to return.

Answer (score 0):

`STR` is defined as a `String[]` but the method signature says it returns a `String`. You need to change it to

```
public static String[] accept_name() { ... }
```

Also, `accept_name` isn't a good name for a method that return an array of Strings, it doesn't conform to Java method naming standards and doesn't really describe what the method does. `STR` is also not a well named variable - it should start with lower case letter and describe what it represents something like `studentNames`. You also don't need the brackets around the variable in the return statement.